# How to add a event on sidebar content in semantic ui?

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui

I am using meteor. I added a sidebar using semantic-ui but when I check click event in sidebar option, my function is not called.

Code of the sidebar:

```
<div id="iconBar" class="ui left vertical menu blue labeled icon iconBar sidebar">
<div id="serach" class="side">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="ui huge list">
            <div class="item">
                <i class="search icon"></i>
                <div class="content">
                    <a class="xyz">Search</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui divider">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my JS:

```
'click #serach': function() {
        alert('hello');
}
```

Comment: could you put your example in a http://jsfiddle.net/ please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is speculative as I don't know Semantic-UI sufficiently well to be sure, but it's very possible that this is the result of the nodes containing the sidebar being moved within then DOM when the sidebar is initialised.  That's what causes event-handlers to fail with modals in Semantic-UI, Foundation and Bootstrap.

Event listeners are attached to the template instance which *originally* contained the template nodes, but if those nodes are then moved within the DOM (by Semantic-UI's sidebar initialisation or otherwise), the events won't bubble up through the containing nodes that those handlers are monitoring any more.

The canonical solution is to make sure you attach event handlers to a template which gets moved either in its entirety or not at all, so that you're sure events will still bubble up through the relevant nodes. Here, that means you need to put a sub-template within the sidebar (so that it all gets moved on initialisation):

```
<div id="iconBar" class="ui left vertical menu blue labeled icon iconBar sidebar">
  {{> sidebarContents}}
</div>

<template name="sidebarContents">
  <div id="serach" class="side">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ui huge list">
        <div class="item">
          <i class="search icon"></i>
          <div class="content">
            <a class="xyz">Search</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="ui divider">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then attach your event handlers to `Template.sidebarContents` instead.